# Adding a Div around the contents of 2 matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a div with class name 'wrapped' around 2 divs with innerHTML 'one' and  'two'

```
<div class='blk'>one</div>
<div class='blk'>two</div>
```

Here I am trying to use the first and second 'clearfix' class element  and use it as a selector to  wrap the contents between them with a    div. What I understand from the below code is wrapAll will wrap only   the matched elements. I am trying to figure out what functionality in  jquery will help me to wrap one and two with a parent div.

```js
var arr = $('.clearfix');

$(arr[0], arr[1]).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"/>');
```

```css
.wrapped {
  background-color: 'red';
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>one</div>
  <div class='blk'>two</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>3</div>
  <div class='blk'>4</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

My expected output is :

```
<div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='wrapped'>
    <div class='blk'>one</div>
    <div class='blk'>two</div> 
  </div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>3</div>
  <div class='blk'>4</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the HTML structure you're trying to create?

Comment: Do you want to wrap one and two in the same div as each other, or each their own divs?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you're wanting to wrap a div (with class `wrapped`) around the two elements (with class `blk`) that contain the text content; "one" and "two".

One way to achieve this would be via the [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector - this allows you to isolate specific elements for the `.blk` class selector (ie the first and second), and than apply wrapping to those only:

```js
/* Select the first and second elements that match the .blk selector
   and apply wrapped div to those only */
$('.blk:eq(0), .blk:eq(1)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"/>');
```

```css
.wrapped{
  background-color: red; /* Fixed syntax error here too :) */
}
.hidden{
  display:  none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class='blk'>one</div>
 <div class='blk'>two</div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class='blk'>3</div>
 <div class='blk'>4</div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `.filter()`

```js
var arr = $('.blk');
arr.filter((i, el) => i < 2).wrapAll(`<div class="wrapped"></div>`);
```

```css
.wrapped{
  background-color: red;
}
.hidden{
  display:  none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class='blk'>one</div>
 <div class='blk'>two</div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class='blk'>3</div>
 <div class='blk'>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clearfixParent = $('.clearfix').parent();

var wrappedEle = 0;
$(clearfixParent).find( 'div' ).each(function(){
 if( $(this).hasClass( 'clearfix' ) ) {
    wrappedEle += 1; 
    $(this).after('<div class="wrapped"/>');
 } else {
    $(this).appendTo( '.wrapped:eq(' + ( wrappedEle - 1 ) + ')' );
 }
});
```

```css
.wrapped {
  background-color: 'red';
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>one</div>
  <div class='blk'>two</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>3</div>
  <div class='blk'>4</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, you can use the DOM API.

```js
const appendSelectedSiblings = selector => target => {
  while (target.nextElementSibling && target.nextElementSibling.matches(selector)) 
    target.appendChild(target.nextElementSibling)
}

document.querySelectorAll('.clearfix').forEach(appendSelectedSiblings('.blk'))
```

```css
.clearfix > .blk { background: green };
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>one</div>
  <div class='blk'>two</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>3</div>
  <div class='blk'>4</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood with the markup you included, you want to enclose/group all the divs with class BLKs that are beside each other.

I made a snippet that will be able to do this dynamically, without specifying the index of your wrap all.

Feel free to update if you could make the code more efficient.

```js
var divs = $(".scan").find("div");
var toEnclose = [];
var continueEnclose;
var latestArray = [];

divs.each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clearfix")) {
    if (latestArray.length != 0) {
      toEnclose.push(latestArray);
      latestArray = [];
    }
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("blk")) {
    latestArray.push(i);
  }
});

if (latestArray.length != 0) {
  toEnclose.push(latestArray);
  latestArray = [];
}

var enclose;
var mix = [];

$.each(toEnclose, function(i, k) {
  $.each($(this), function(i2, k2) {
    if (i != 0) {
      k2 += i;
    }
    mix.push(".scan div:eq(" + k2 + ")");
  });

  enclose = mix.join(",");
  // console.log(enclose);
  $(enclose).wrapAll($("<div class='wrapped'></div>"));
  mix = [];
});
```

```css
.wrapped {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scan">
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>one</div>
  <div class='blk'>two</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>3</div>
  <div class='blk'>4</div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
  <div class='blk'>5</div>
  <div class='blk'>6</div>
  <div class='blk'>7</div>
</div>
```